# mail is not sent through SMTP

Tags: emails

Im trying to send an HTML mail through SMTP, Im currently using the modules:

- MIME mail
- PHPMailer
- Mail System

On a Drupal 7 site.

The problem is that when I check the mail header that I have recivied it does not say Amazon SES which I have configured PHPmailer to do so but my hosts information

Following is my code.

```
function mail_subscribers($email_body, $email_subject, $subscribed_users) {
  $module = 'my_module';
  //$key = microtime();
  $key = 'mymodule_mailer';
  //$subscribed_users = get_subscribed_users($feed_nid, $users_type);
  $params['headers'] = array(
    'Bcc' => $subscribed_users,
  );
  $to = 'welcome@mysite.com';
  $subject = $email_subject;
  //$params ='';
  $body[] = $email_body;
  $send = FALSE;
  $mail_message = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, language_default(), $params, $send);
  $mail_message['subject'] = $subject;
  $mail_message['body'] = $body;
```

$mail_system = drupal_mail_system($module, $key);
  $mail_message = $mail_system->format($mail_message);
  $mail_message['result'] = $mail_system->mail($mail_message);
}

and my hook_mail

```
function mymodule_mail ($key, &$message, $params) {
  switch ($key) {
    case 'mymodule_mailer':
      // Set headers etc

      $message['send'] = FALSE;

      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: you've set `$send` to `FALSE` in 1st and again `$message['send']` to `FALSE` in second function. Ideally it should not send any mail ;-)

Comment: But it does, Thats actually what Im worried about the most. when I set $send to false nothing happens and two mails actually get sent, But when I add the hook_mail $message to false only one is sent.

Comment: @indrock Could it be my $params variable?

Comment: A single mail will be sent evertime to code is executed because you use object returned `drupal_mail_system` to send mail on the very last line of the first function. And if you set `$send` to `TRUE` then it should send 2.

Comment: @indrock Im not really following here, Could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you set the `$send` to be false, `drupal_mail` function will not send the mail, instead only compose and keep it in the memory. This composed mail is sent when you call `$mail_system->mail($mail_message)` at the last line of the first function. So, your code should send one mail (on last line) everytime; using code at the last line. If you set `$send` as TRUE, then a mail will be sent using `drupal_mail` function and also from the last line (hence two mails when `$send` is set to TRUE.

Comment: @indrock Could we carry on this on chat? The mail not being sent is not the problem but its not being sent through the SMTP. Using the implementation above I do get an email, But not from amazon SES server but from my host